# User is getting registered But the Toast message showing up is "Failed to Register! Try Again!"(Firebase)

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

This is basically an issue on GitHub which I tried to solve. Before implementing it in the main app I tried out it in a demo app of mine. The code was working fine. When I implemented the code in the main app User is getting registered But the Toast message showing up is "Failed to Register! Try Again!". The code is the same as that of the demo app. I am not getting why this is happening. Can someone please help?
Link of Demo app: https://github.com/Khushi-24/Firebase-Email-authentication-Demo.

Forked Repo:https://github.com/Khushi-24/CSwala-android/tree/email_login

In the main App Code for Registration

```
public class Register extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    EditText txtemail, txtpassword;
    Button btn_register;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    ImageView banner;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        txtemail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_email);
        txtpassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_password);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.proressBar);
        banner = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.banner);
        banner.setOnClickListener(this);

        btn_register = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);
        btn_register.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.buttonRegister:
                registerUser();
                break;
        }

    }

    private void registerUser() {
        final String email = txtemail.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = txtpassword.getText().toString().trim();

        if (email.isEmpty()) {
            txtemail.setError("Email is required");
            txtemail.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if (password.isEmpty()) {
            txtpassword.setError("Password is required");
            txtpassword.requestFocus();
            return;
        }


        if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()){
            txtemail.setError("Please provide valid email!");
            txtemail.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if(password.length() < 6){
            txtpassword.setError("Min Password length should be 6 characters!");
            txtpassword.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            User user = new User(email);

                            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                                    .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                                    .setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                        Toast.makeText(Register.this, "User has been Registered Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    }else{
                                        Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Failed to Register! Try Again!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Failed to Register! Try Again!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.cswala.cswala"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.2.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.4.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:6.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.6.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.cachapa:ExpandableLayout:2.9.2'

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.1.0')
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'
    // FirebaseUI for Firebase Realtime Database
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:6.3.0'

    // FirebaseUI for Cloud Firestore
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:6.2.1'

    // FirebaseUI for Firebase Auth
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.2.1'

    // FirebaseUI for Cloud Storage
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:6.2.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:18.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:22.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.7.0'

    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'

    //Android Jetpack Navigation
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.3"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.3"

    //Glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0'

    //custom Bottom nav bar
    implementation 'com.ismaeldivita.chipnavigation:chip-navigation-bar:1.3.4'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.21'

    //App Intro
    implementation 'com.github.AppIntro:AppIntro:6.1.0'
    //EasyPref
    implementation 'com.pixplicity.easyprefs:library:1.9.0'
    //Animatoo Library
    implementation 'com.github.mohammadatif:Animatoo:master'


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's nothing wrong with your code.
You may not have enabled Authentication with email in your firebase console
and the question is vague, instead of your Toasting Error, Please try again maybe get the actual exception like `Log.d("ERROR", task.getException());`

```
firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            User user = new User(email);

                            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                                    .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                                    .setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                        Toast.makeText(Register.this, "User has been Registered Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    }else{
                                        Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Error: "+ task.getException().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        Log.d("ERROR", task.getException());
                                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Error: "+ task.getException().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Log.d("ERROR", task.getException());
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Email Authentication is enabled without that user can't log in. Here the user is able to log in, receiving mail to verify the email just the thing is that even after the user is getting registered the message showing up is like "Failed ... ".

Comment: Try this code in the answer and tell me what the Toast says